# C strtok() delim

Tags: c, string, delimiter, strtok

I need some clarification about the function `strtok()`

Lets say my delimiter is a string that is `"SEP"`

And I have a string that is like this: `char str[100] = "var1SEPvar2SEPvar3SEPvar4";`

Would doing `strtok(str, "SEP");`

Give me `var1, var2, var3, var4`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the result will be as you are expecting provided that the var1, var2, var3 and var4 contain neither character from the string `"SEP"`.

That is the function does not search the word `"SEP"` in the source string. It considers each character in the string `"SEP"` like a delimiter character.

Otherwise you should use standard C function `strstr` to search string `"SEP"` yourself using the function.